# Hot to create an AWS ECS resource before an image is available in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs

To Devs,
I am using Terraform to spin up resources in AWS, resources are ECS in Fargate mode. On first run, I will not have an image to create the Task with but I would like to set up all the other necessary resources (ECS, Service, Task Group, Task Definition, Autoscaling). GitLab CI CD would build the image, push the image and create the Task. Terraform is complaining that the Task Definition can not be defined without the image.
What are my options?
Thanks,
Marc

Comment: Build and push the image first, before you try to use it!?

Comment: Yes, that is the only way I have come up with.  Am considering a one-off to put a dummy image in the ECR for creation of the ECS.  Other people have run into the same problem. Thanks

Comment: use terrform "depends_on" feature to first push the image and then create the task definition & the service.